# How to count two different columns in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stackexchange, dataexplorer

I am playing with the StackOverflow datadump. Now I have a T-SQL Problem:

I can select a list with the number of questions per month and year with:

```
select datepart(year, posts.creationdate) as year,
datepart(month, posts.creationdate) as month, 
count(distinct posts.id) as questions
from posts
inner join posttags on posttags.postid = posts.id
inner join tags on tags.id = posttags.tagid
where posts.posttypeid = 1
group by datepart(month, posts.creationdate), 
datepart(year, posts.creationdate)
order by datepart(year, posts.creationdate), 
datepart(month, posts.creationdate)
```

If I add `and tags.tagname = 'scala'` on the `WHERE`-row, then I get the number of all "scala-questions". Is there any way I can show both the total number of questions and the number of questions containing a specific tag in the same result set (in different columns).

Because when I add the `and tags.tagname = 'scala'` I can no longer see the total number of questions per month.

Any ideas on how I can unit these resultsets into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `left outer join` against `posttags`,  `count(posttags.tagid)` will only count non null values. And since the left outer join only contain `scala` tags, you can skip the `distinct` in `count(distinct posts.id)`.

```
select datepart(year, posts.creationdate) as year,
       datepart(month, posts.creationdate) as month,
       count(*) as questions,
       count(posttags.tagid) as sc
from posts
  left outer join posttags
    on posttags.postid = posts.id and
       posttags.tagid = (select id
                         from tags
                         where tagname = 'scala')
where posts.posttypeid = 1
group by datepart(month, posts.creationdate),
         datepart(year, posts.creationdate)
order by datepart(year, posts.creationdate),
         datepart(month, posts.creationdate)
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107948/

Comment: Mikael - I never thought i would see the day where you forget to join your tables. posttags.tagid = (select id from tags where tagname = 'scala' and posttags.tagid = id)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk . I did not. The sub query will only return one row/value. The ID for 'scala' is `3143` so the join could have been written using `3143` instead of having a sub query to return the value. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107949/

Answer (score 2):

You'd need two queries to do that, since you have two sets of data (questions by month and scala questions by month). One possible solution is using [common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to create two "temporary views" of the data. As an example:

```
with total as (
    select datepart(year, posts.creationdate) as year,
           datepart(month, posts.creationdate) as month, 
           count(distinct posts.id) as questions
    from posts
        inner join posttags on posttags.postid = posts.id
        inner join tags on tags.id = posttags.tagid
    where posts.posttypeid = 1
    group by datepart(month, posts.creationdate), datepart(year, posts.creationdate)
), scala as (
    select datepart(year, posts.creationdate) as year,
           datepart(month, posts.creationdate) as month, 
           count(distinct posts.id) as questions
    from posts
        inner join posttags on posttags.postid = posts.id
        inner join tags on tags.id = posttags.tagid
     where posts.posttypeid = 1 and tags.tagname = 'scala'
    group by datepart(month, posts.creationdate), datepart(year, posts.creationdate)
)
select total.year, total.month, total.questions as total_questions, scala.questions as scala_questions
from total
    join scala on total.year = scala.year and total.month = scala.month
order by total.year, total.month​
```

The results of which can be seen [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107921/).